# "Feel it in my bones"

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Does "Feel it in my bones" sound natural? I have never seen or heard any native speakers use something like that, except in a subtitle of a movie I watched long ago.

What are other phrases, or common ways to state something similar?

Answer (score 5):

"Feel it in my bones" is a valid statement, and sounds entirely natural. The origin of this saying comes from someone who has athritis, or rheumatism, and when cold and wet weather approaches, they will be able to feel [pain in their bones. :](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/feel%20in%20one%27s%20bones)

> Have an intuition or hunch about something, as in "I'm sure he'll succeed I can feel it in my bones ."  This expression alludes to the age-old notion that persons with a healed broken bone or with arthritis experience bone pain before rain, due to a drop in barometric pressure, and therefore can predict a weather change. [c. 1600]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is indeed an English phrase. You'd more likely say "I can feel it in my bones", which means "My intuition is telling me so."

Answer (score 3):

To say something like, "I feel it in my bones!" is to use an English [idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+feel+it+in+my+bones) which means:

> something that you say when you are certain something is true or will happen, although you have no proof

Options could be:

- I have a hunch
- I've got a gut feeling
- I can feel it

All of these imply that the speaker has some internal feeling which leads him to believe something, whether or not there are facts to support it.