# What does "in my bones" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I can't get the meaning of the phrase "in my bones". Help me make a suitable sentence using it. Does it have a positive connotation?

Comment: Sing it? Is that what you mean to say?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Feel it in my bones"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36717/feel-it-in-my-bones)

Comment: What resources have you checked? What did the dictionaries say? What did searching this very site return? What is the context you are looking at? The phrase has a literal meaning and a metaphorical one, which one are you after? We can't tell if you don't tell us. And what is a "suitable sentence"? Suitable for what? Lastly, please do proofread before posting. If you expect people to put the absolute minimum effort into their answers, you must put the absolute minimum effort into your questions.

Answer (score 2):

[(feel it) in my bones](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/feel-it-in-your-bones):

> to believe something strongly although you cannot explain why: It's going to be a good summer - *I can feel it in my bones*. - Cambridge Dictionary Online